# Gesture not recognized (2 finger double tap) : Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Problem: upgraded to newer Xcode and supporting ios 11 now. (my app doesn't need it, but forced by Apple not supporting interface builder files any more - get error message when trying to upload app to the app store).

The code seems like it is pretty simple (doesn't it always!).
I have created a sample, minimal, example and attached it.
Simple single page app. Load  a view and recognize some gestures.
So the single tap gesture works. The double tap does not.
The double tap is recognized as 2 single taps (maybe reasonable).
I removed the single tap getsure and tried to trigger the handler for the 2 finger 2 tap gesture.
Doesn't get recognized.
Had both working for ios5.x using an empty nib file.

Here is the appDelegate file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds] ;
    self.appViewController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.appViewController;
    //@property(nullable, nonatomic,strong) UIViewController *rootViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);  // from "UIWindow"

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return YES;
}
```

ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (retain,readwrite) UITapGestureRecognizer       *twoFingerDoubleTap_yyz;
@property (retain,readwrite) UITapGestureRecognizer       *oneFinger;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //add gesture Double tap to open a view.

    self.twoFingerDoubleTap_yyz = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:(id)self action:@selector ( twoFingerDoubleTap:) ];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.twoFingerDoubleTap_yyz];
    self.twoFingerDoubleTap_yyz.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    self.twoFingerDoubleTap_yyz.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

    /*
    self.oneFinger = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:(id)self action:@selector ( oneFingerTap:) ];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.oneFinger];
    self.oneFinger.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.oneFinger.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
*/
}


-(IBAction)twoFingerDoubleTap:        (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"i'm here 2 !");
}

-(IBAction)oneFingerTap:        (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"i'm here 1 !");
}

@end
```

The code seems so simple, so I would like to blame the problem on Xcode (maybe new 9.1 does not recognize double tap?) or on ios11. But since I don't see anyone else with the problem, I have to think I am missing something - maybe even obvious?
(NOTE: I haven't tried it on a real device, since I done't have anything running more than ios7.x at this time. My original iPad needs an upgrade - finally!?)

Update: (moved from comment section into here, since it is pretty relevant) The two finger single tap also worked in tests. Just not the 2 finger double tap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing, I have come to the conclusion that the simulator is the culprit. Normally to simulate 2 fingers you push the option key down. Previous simulators everything worked as expected. In this simulator, the holding down of the **option key is "undone" after the first tap**. 
In the past I was able to hold the option key down and double tap the keypad. Doesn't work with Xcode 9.1.
WORKAROUND:(harder to do/use) is to try to double tap the option key and the keypad at the same time. A lot more difficult to do, so quite inconvenient for testing.
I have raised an apple bug report and will now update it with this information. Bug number:#35671917
(is there a way to view bugs(other peoples) on that website or is it a "write only" hide all issues website?)

Further note : I also confirmed that there is no problem when running on a real device that was using ios9.3.5. The gestures were all recognized as expected.

Update:

Apple claims this is a duplicate of an existing bug,(although we would have no way to know that, since it is a top secret database, that the world cannot browse(except your own problem reports), but can add records to) so maybe a fix is in the works or maybe not - They don't divulge that type of information.

Comment: I am on Xcode 13.2.1 and still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code, and if you remove the following line:

```
self.twoFingerDoubleTap_yyz.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
```

It all seems to work fine my end.

Comment: But I did want a 2 finger double tap. I also tried what you said and id did not work for me!? Huummm? Correction - single finger double tap did work. It is the 2 finger version that is not working, though.

Comment: It works taking the number of touches out but keeping the number of taps.

Comment: Yah it also works 2 fingers 1 tap. -just tried that also. That eliminates my thought of xcode not recognizing the double touch.

Comment: was missing some code in the appDelegate. just added it now. I am starting to think the problem has to do with linking the UIResponder somehow?

Comment: Apple has acknowledged a bug, but in their usual secretaive / don't admit wrong ways - Apple stated the problem was a "DUPLICATE OF 31829654". Status:OPEN. No further details on date. no possibility of viewing the bug description or status. (That was on Dec 4 2017)

Answer (score 0):

Taps and touches are different. Tap tells number of tap( single, double etc.) . Touches tells number of fingers per tap. So you need two tapgesture recognizers for each tap number. You can add any number of recognizers onto uiview

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Swift 4`, and two finger double taps do not work for me in the simulator(iPhone 8 Plus) in `Xcode 9.01` nor in the simulator in `Xcode 9.2`.  I tried your workaround, but I was unable to get it to work (Edit: Well, I finally did get it to work a couple of times!).  One finger double taps work fine by putting my mouse pointer on the ImageView and clicking twice on my Macbook Pro trackpad.

I'm using an ImageView to recognize gestures.  Thanks to [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/433-uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-getting-started) for pointing out that by default an ImageView does not allow user interaction--you have to open the Attributes Inspector and check `User Interaction Enabled` for gestures to work.  I have added gestures to the ImageView so that a single finger double tap will display the next image, and a two finger double tap is supposed to display the previous image.  Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    let images = [
        "IMG_0306.jpg",
        "IMG_0319.jpg",
        "IMG_0293.jpg"
    ]
    var imageIndex = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tapRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        tapRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        tapRecognizer1.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1  //number of fingers
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer1)

        ///

        let tapRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        tapRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        tapRecognizer2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer2)

    }


    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("in handle tap")

        if (sender.numberOfTouchesRequired == 1) {
            print("\t -- number of fingers == 1")

            imageIndex += 1
            if imageIndex == images.count {
                imageIndex = 0
            }
        } else if sender.numberOfTouchesRequired == 2 {
            print("\t -- number of fingers == 2")

            imageIndex -= 1
            if imageIndex == -1 {
                imageIndex = images.count - 1
            }
        }

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[imageIndex])
    }
}
```

In Xcode, I see output like this:

```
in handle tap
     -- number of fingers == 1
in handle tap
 -- number of fingers == 2   //It's hard to make this happen!
```

In my project, I have a folder with three images:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems to match my findings, exactly. I also learned the hard way that UIView and UIImageView do not share the same default values for interaction. I just went back to that version to confirm that I did have this set (correctly) for my real code (as opposed to the sample for this site) before I subbmitted the problem - and yes I did. I have not to date, received any updates on the bug status in Apples database. (not holding my breath either...lol)